# R Regular expression for string containing full stops

Tags: regex, r

I have a bunch of strings, some of which end with `..t.`. I am trying to find a regular expression to match these strings but dealing with the full stops is giving me a headache!

I have tried

```
grep('^.+(..t.)$', myStrings)
```

but this also matches strings such as `w...gate`. I think I am dealing with the full stops incorrectly. Any help at all appreciated.

Note: I am using grep within R.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are only checking if the end of the string ends with `..t.`, you can eliminate `^.+` in your pattern.

The dot `.` in  regular expression syntax is a [character of special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) which matches any character except a newline sequence. To match a literal dot or any other character of special meaning you need to escape `\\` it.

```
> x <- c('foo..t.', 'w...gate', 'bar..t.foo', 'bar..t.')
> grep('\\.{2}t\\.$', x)
# [1] 1 4
```

Or place that character inside of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
> x <- c('foo..t.', 'w...gate', 'bar..t.foo', 'bar..t.')
> grep('[.]{2}t[.]$', x)
# [1] 1 4
```

**Note:** I used the range operator `\\.{2}` to match two dots instead of escaping it twice `\\.\\.`

Comment: This is definitely better! Thanks. Will wait a day and if no better solutions arise (I doubt it) will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

k, a little bit of better googling provided the answer;

```
 grep("^.+(\\.\\.t\\.)$", myStrings)
```

this works because we need to escape the point as `\\.` in R.

Comment: I know - answering within 1 minute shows poor research. I think I just hit upon a better google search term - genuinely not trying to spam SO.

Comment: Suppose you have a string `str1 <- c("something..t.", "w...gate", "w1..tg", "w2..t.g5", "w1...t.")` The code matches 1 and 5.  Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, that's intended - he string must end with `..t.`. Anything before that is valid

Answer (score 0):

The dot(`.`) matches only a single character.. to remove meaning of dot u should use double slash before dot char (`\\`).

try this instead.....

```
grep('^.+(\\.\\.t\\.)$', myStrings)
```

Satheesh Appu

Comment: Yes David, you are right. Have to escape \ like this grep('^\\.+(\\.\\.t\\.)$', myStrings)